# Bitbucket webhook trigger after pipeline completes successfully

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'd like to trigger a webhook after a pipeline completes successfully, I looked in the trigger list and didn't find any, is there a workaround to trigger webhook manually via pipeliens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Build status updated](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/event-payloads-740262817.html#EventPayloads-Buildstatusupdated) trigger to trigger a webhook based on a pipelines build. However, this will also be triggered by the INPROGRESS or FAILED state, and there is no possibility to specify a pipeline.

If you only want to trigger a webhook from when a specific pipeline completes succesfully, you can do this manually by adding the necessary commands to your `bitbucket-pipelines.yaml` file.

If you have multiple parallel steps in your pipeline, you should add the webhook trigger in a separate serial step, so it only runs when all parallel steps have completed.